# Error in Selenium tests triggered from batch script in TFS Build step

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Step 1. I have written selenium tests and bundled it into executable jar.

Step 2. When I execute this jar tests runs normally. Invokes New browser and execute all steps.

Step 3. I created bat file to execute this jar. In this case also test execution happens normally.

Step 4. TFS Build integration. (TFS 2015)
        - I created new build definition in TFS 
        - Added build step "Batch Script"
        - Entered path of bat file created in step 3 in build step
        - When I Queue this build. bat file gets called and test execution 
starts. **But It does not open new browser**..console says Started IE driver...it starts driver internal to build agent. and execution fails on setting value in textbox.

[Click to see TFS Build Cosole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuWAk.png)

I can't use Visual studio tests. Requirement is to selenium tests should be triggered from jar created on Step 1.

Comment: Step 2 and 3 are executed on remote build server(the build agent located). Execution happens normally.  Also TFS build service account used is administrator and has all permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the build agent is running in [interactive mode](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows#choose-interactive-or-service-mode).

Answer (score 0):

First you could try to RDP to the remote build server(the build agent located) and manually run the batch file to see if it works.

If it's also not work then the issue may related the IE browser on the server.

If it works then maybe the TFS **build service account** don't have enough permission to run the IE driver. Please make sure the build service account has local Admin permission on the build server.

Comment: Step 2 and 3 are executed on remote build server(the build agent located). Execution happens normally.  Also TFS build service account used is administrator and has all permissions.

Comment: For  further troubleshooting , on the variables tab of the build definition, add **system.debug** and set it to true. Select to allow at queue time. To see if you could get some related info.